# Text Input inside Alert in React Native

Tags: react-native

How to place multiple line text input inside Alert in react native
Something like this..

[image: This is the alert i want]

Answer (score 4):

A custom component with [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) may help you achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you could add a multiple line text input to the Alert component.  According to the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/alert.html), it accepts a title, message, buttons and type only. You will need to create a custom component by yourself in order to achieve that.